# How to install the .Net Compact Framework on a Windows CE Device

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks, windows-ce, pocket

I have a pocket PC/scanner that runs on windows CE. I put a C# program on it, but when I tried running it, an error appears which says that I need to install the .NET Compact Framework v4.0. I have tried downloading the files for it which I found online and running it on the pocket PC but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest release of the .NET CF is version 3.9 that is available only for devices running Windows Embedded Compact 2013.
On older releases you may install .NET CF 3.5 or 2.0 (3.5 is supported from CE 4.2, 2.0 from 4.0 IRRC) by downloading the files from MS website or just deploying your application from your development PC.
Which kind of device are you using, do you know the Windows CE release used?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I am running Windows CE Version 6.00 and the device is a Motorolla MC9190

Comment: Then you should be able to run .NET CF 3.5 on it, not 3.9.